# NSException during a objectAtIndex

Tags: iphone, xcode, dictionary, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm using HTTP request for my iPhone App. When I want to made the dictionnary, there is a NSException...

```
[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector
```

Here's the code for the connectionDidFinishLoading :

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
[connection release];

NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"responseString");
NSLog(responseString);

[responseData release];
NSArray *tableau = [responseString JSONValue];
NSLog(@"the newt line give me the exception");
NSDictionary *dico = [tableau objectAtIndex:0];
```

responseString give me that:

```
{"token":"8569fe2e095d83a4692812fa808f84da"}
```

I used that code before but it want not run with those datas...

If you can help me, it would be very nice!
Thank You !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in JSON are delimited by `[]`, whilst objects/dictionaries are delimited by `{}`. Since your response is

```
{"token":"8569fe2e095d83a4692812fa808f84da"}
```

it is not an array — it’s a single object/dictionary.

Try:

```
NSDictionary *dico = [responseString JSONValue];
```

Comment: @cle Do you mean that the application is killed and no error shows up?

Comment: Hum actually It's killing just after... I used [dico objectForKey:@key] and I expect that that line cause me the problem. I tried to add "[" and "]" and use my old methods but apparently it doesn't working too ...

Comment: @cle It should be `[dico objectForKey:@"token"]`. Have you tried that?

Comment: it's what I've used, yes ;-) I had put NSLog("flag"); instread of NSLog(@"flag") ... hum...